# Windows 8 - Missing 'Balanced' Power Plan

Tags: windows-8, power-supply, power, power-options, energy

I've seen a similar (although not the same) question here [Default Power Plan options apart from Balanced have disappeared, how to restore them?](https://superuser.com/questions/916228/default-power-plan-options-apart-from-balanced-have-disappeared-how-to-restore) but I did not understand what to do. Basically, when I go to the Power Plan Option, the only two plans available are now 'High Performance' and 'Power Saver'. I have look through the 'powercfg' options in the CMD and it seems like the 'Balanced' Power Plan still exists, albeit with no name (when I use the -list command, it lists it with the name '*'; although weirdly, it does recognize the plan when using the -aliases command, and lists it as scheme_balanced. I actually set it with -setactive, but the Power Plan Options displays as if I didn't have any plan active (hence I cannot tweak what I want to tweak from there). -duplicatescheme does not seem to be able to duplicate it either, saying that combination does not exist.

Comment: Update the power driver for the machine (Support Website). Then run DISM and SFC.   Open an admin command prompt and run  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  and then follow this with SFC /SCANNOW   .   Restart and see if you have a Power Plan showing that you can adjust.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the Power Driver you're referring to (HP provides none). As for SFC and DISM, I already ran them. Some errors came up, they were fixed. But nothing related to Power apparently.

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop. HP may have a Power Manager application - try that if a desktop. If a laptop, there will be a power driver  and install that. If nothing works, you will need to do a Windows 8 / 8.1 Reset which keeps data and Windows 8 drivers and built in software but not your own applications

Comment: This is a laptop. HP Pavilion 14-f002la. There doesn't seem to be a Power Drive, except for 'ENERGY STAR Qualified Power Plan' and 'HP CoolSense Technology'. Which can be found here: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Pavilion-14-Sleekbook/5375393/model/5403357
But rather than drivers, they look like 3rd party software, so I'm not sure if those are needed.

Comment: So uh, funnily enough, I installed Energy Star, and it seems now I can't see any energy plan, instead it says 'the info for energy plans is not available'. I can't even change any options like brightness, etc. I'm running sfc now and will run dism later. I don't really want to do a reset, so I hope there's a solution to this :/.

Comment: If anyone needs a solution for this, I solved it. Just export your 'balanced' plan from another computer, then import it to your faulty one. Works like a charm.